# Supplying dynamic pattern (YYYYMMDD) as ftp mget pattern

Tags: bash, ftp, mget

I am writing a script that supposed fetch today's files (about a dozen) from an FTP site using `mget` like so

```
ftp -n XX.XX.XX.XX <<END_SCRIPT
mget *20190703*
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Ideally I'd do something like `mget 'date +%Y%m%d'` (apostrophe used in lieu of a literal backtick) but that's not possible. I'd appreciate any pointers

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible?

Comment: the here-doc is a (by default double-ish) quoted string, so you should be able to embed the dynamic date with `mget *$(date +%Y%m%d)*`, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code segment should work: Kindly check.

```
event_date=`date +%Y%m%d`
ftp -n -i XX.XX.XX.XX <<END_SCRIPT
mget *${event_date}*
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

or you may look in below script: we use this script in production

```
event_date=`date +%Y%m%d`
lftp -p [port number] -u user_name,'password' sftp://ip <<HERE_DOC
cd file_directory
mget *${event_date}*
bye
HERE_DOC
```

Comment: I'm getting `mget file1_20190701.ext? mget file2_20190701.ext? mget file1_20190701.ext? ...` . As I see `mget` is waiting for prompts.

Comment: you will get all files with \*20190701\*pattern ... use second  code segment ... it wont ask for password ... using in hundreds script .... btw if port is default ... then no need to give that data.

Comment: Unfortunately the backup device I am copying to only supports FTP (_boo_). I think its because mget has sync features tho.

Comment: Update adding the flag `-i` seems to do the trick i.e. `ftp -n -i XX.XX.XX.XX`

Comment: @Olumide its really odd. However, still this can be handled I guess. Try to write a  loop.